# To neighbor inline elements inside the block element

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML markup:

```
<div>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <span>Another some text</span>
    <p>This is <s>sparta</s> paragraph</p>
</div>
```

In the spec in [sec. 9.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) said the following:

> A block container box either contains only block-level boxes or
>   establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only
>   inline-level boxes.

Is it true that two neighbor `span` elements are wrapped in an anonymous block?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Why does spec said, that `A block container box either contains only block-level boxes or establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only inline-level boxes.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in the sense that you won't find an anonymous block in the DOM.

But for the purposes of layout, you can *think of those elements* as if they were in fact enclosed in an anon block; to put it differently, explicitly wrapping them in an unstyled block element will not result in any observable layout difference.

The purpose of this rule is most likely (I 'm not a W3C insider) to reduce the number of possibilities that a layout engine has to deal with and thus make implementing and validating one easier.

Comment: So in fact we haven't an anon block which wrapped the two span elements. But how does understand the following `A block container box either contains only block-level boxes or establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only inline-level boxes.`? How this rule can be applied in my case?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: The spec says that a layout engine needs to deal only with two cases: (a) either only block boxes, or (b) only inline boxes. However, HTML allows option (c): a mix of the two. In that case, the layout engine should pretend that inline siblings are wrapped inside a block box which reduces the problem to case (a). I don't understand how that "applies" in your case, or even what your case is (unless you are writing a layout engine).

Comment: Your comments dispel my doubts finally. Many thanks.